# Split text file into array based on an empty line or any non used character

Tags: arrays, bash, ascii, echo, ifs

I have a text file which contains text lines separated by an empty line of text. I want to push the content of that file into an array, and use the empty line as a separator. I tried IFS="\n" (or "\r\n" etc..) but couldn't get it to work so instead I thought I would replace any empty line by a character that isn't in the file, so I picked up the spanish inverted question mark (\xBF)

```
sed 's/^$/'$(echo -e "\xBF")'/'))
```

So that works, I have a character that I'll use to slice my file and put it into an array.(Bit of a random trick but hey that's just one way of doing it ..)

Now I need to change $IFS so it will use the inverted question mark to slice up the data for the array.

If I type

```
IFS=$(echo -e "\xBF")
```

in the command line it works just fine

```
 echo "$IFS"
¿
```

But if I type that command with a trailing read -a then it does nothing :

```
[user@machine ~]$ IFS=$(echo -e "\xBF") read -a array <<< "$var"
[user@machine ~]$ echo "$IFS"
[user@machine ~]$
```

So that's weird because $var has a value.

Even more surprising, when I verify the value of IFS right after I get :

```
[user@machine ~]$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
0000000  sp  ht  nl
    040 011 012
         \t  \n
0000003
[user@machine ~]$
```

Which is the default value for IFS.

I am pretty sure one can use any character for IFS, no ?

Alternatively, if you have any trick up your sleeve to split a file in an array with a split based on empty lines I am interested ! (still I'd like to get to the bottom of this for comprehension's sake).

Thanks very much, and have a good week-end :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, by design, variables set with `var=foo command` are only made available to `command` and won't be set for the rest of the script.

As for your problem, `read` reads a record until the first delimiter (`-d`, default: line feed), and then splits that up into fields by `$IFS`.

To loop over your items, you can use

```
sed -e 's/^$/\xBF/' | while read -d $'\xBF' var
do
    printf "Value: %s\n-----\n" "$var"
done
```

To read them all into an array from a string, you can read up until some character you hopefully don't have, like a NUL byte:

```
IFS=$'\xBF' read -d '' -a array <<< "$var"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure what "yourcommand" should be though. Would you mind explaining? Thank you !:)

Comment: That would be your command for producing `\xBF` separated items, which you only seemed specify parts of in the question. I've updated it with that.

Answer (score 5):

This script should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
s=1
declare -a arr
while read -r line 
do
    # If we find an empty line, then we increase the counter (i), 
    # set the flag (s) to one, and skip to the next line
    [[ $line == "" ]] && ((i++)) && s=1 && continue 

    # If the flag (s) is zero, then we are not in a new line of the block
    # so we set the value of the array to be the previous value concatenated
    # with the current line
    [[ $s == 0 ]] && arr[$i]="${arr[$i]}
$line" || { 
            # Otherwise we are in the first line of the block, so we set the value
            # of the array to the current line, and then we reset the flag (s) to zero 
            arr[$i]="$line"
            s=0; 
    }
done < file

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "================"
   echo "$i"
done
```

Test file:

```
$ cat file
asdf dsf s dfsdaf s
sadfds fdsa fads f dsaf as

fdsafds f dsf ds afd f saf dsf
sdfsfs dfadsfsaf

sdfsafds fdsafads fd saf adsfas
sdfdsfds fdsfd saf dsa fds fads f
```

Output:

```
================
asdf dsf s dfsdaf s
sadfds fdsa fads f dsaf as
================
fdsafds f dsf ds afd f saf dsf
sdfsfs dfadsfsaf
================
sdfsafds fdsafads fd saf adsfas
sdfdsfds fdsfd saf dsa fds fads f
```

Update:

In order to ignore lines beginning with `#`, you can add this line after the `do`:

```
[[ $line =~ ^# ]] && continue
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine but I don't understand what's happening in the while loop.Would you mind explaining please? :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bluz added an explenation. Let me know if you need any additional clarifications.

Comment: Great thanks very much! I understand the flag thing, although I am trying to grep the file to remove the comments in my original file (lines beginning with a #) but I am struggling...Not sure where to put my grep -vE "^[#]*" . Would you be able to help ? I promise I'll stop with my questions after that! :) Thanks again for your help ! :)

Comment: @Bluz why not do `grep -vE '^[#]' oldfile > newfile` and then run the script with on the new file?

Comment: mmm I suppose could do that but when the script will run into production that won't be one single file but thousands of files into one directory so I am a bit reluctant to create a large temporary file like cat directory/* | grep -vE '^[#]' > newfile.

In an ideal world, it'd be better if I could do it all within the RAM space exclusively.

Comment: @Bluz Then you can just add `[[ $line =~ ^# ]] && continue` right after the `do` line (updated)